# CSRF code not working

Tags: php, csrf

I am reading a book "Essential PHP Security" by Chris Shifflet. There is a chapter on CSRF, where the author recommends using token to prevent CSRF. The code in the book says to add a token in a form we use

```
<?php

session_start();
$token = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE));
$_SESSION['token'] = $token;
$_SESSION['token_time'] = time();

?>

<form action="buy.php" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $token; ?>" />
<p>
Item:
<select name="item">
    <option name="pen">pen</option>
    <option name="pencil">pencil</option>
</select><br />
Quantity: <input type="text" name="quantity" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Buy" />
</p>
</form>
```

and the token can be checked with a simple conditional statement.

```
<?php

if (isset($_SESSION['token']) && $_POST['token']== $_SESSION['token'])
    {
        echo $_POST['token'];
        echo "form passed";
    }
```

But the above code does not seem to work. The "form passed" message does not shows. What is wrong with the above code?. The first set of codes generate the token but there isn't a success message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `session_start();` top of that codes in `buy.php`. Example...

```
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['token']) && $_POST['token']== $_SESSION['token'])
{
    echo $_POST['token'];
    echo "form passed";
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked. Wonder why do they publish books with so much error. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to do it in function efficient manner:

```
session_start();
 function generate_token(){
    $token = uniqid(rand(), true);
    $_SESSION['token'] = $token;
    $_SESSION['token_time'] = time();
 }


 //avoid putting script at bottom until required
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && !empty($_POST)){
if(isset($_SESSION['token']) && isset($_SESSION['token_time']) && 
 isset($_POST['token']))
  {

 if($_SESSION['token'] == $_POST['token'])
 {

    $timestamp_ancien = time() - (15*60);
    //Si le jeton n'est pas expiré
    if($_SESSION['token_time'] >= $timestamp_ancien)
    {
        //here Instruction  
        generate_token();//for next call


     }else{echo"error3";}
    }else{echo"error2";}
    }else{echo"error1";}
}
generate_token();
```

**Reason:** you can put that function anywhere common in your project and include or require the file to use this code without writing it every where.